# ionic 2 throws : Could not find IonicModule.forRoot call in "imports"

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am now adding ionic 2 into my current angular4 project.

In the app.module,

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
@NgModule( {
    imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot( AppComponent )],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but when I use "ionic serve", I kept having this error:

```
00:00:15]  ionic-app-script task: "serve" 
[00:00:15]  Error: Could not find IonicModule.forRoot call in "imports" 
Error: Could not find IonicModule.forRoot call in "imports"
```

Obviously, i is already there, why the error is still thrown?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Go to "app.module.ts" in the src/app folder (src/app/app.module.ts)
- Open it
- Search for "imports"

  ```
   imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       HttpClientModule,
     ]
  ```
- Insert the following line :

  ```
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module from `ionic-angular`.

```
import {IonicApp, IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app.module

```
import { IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';
```